# Trello: How to search current board for keyword or phrase

Tags: trello

In Trello, how can I search the current board for a card containing a keyword or phrase.

I've searched around the internet for a solution to this, but it appears something has changed, and the methods described are outdated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the right-hand menu, select `Filter Cards`.

I believe this feature has been tricky to search for on the interwebs because I was using the keywords "search" and "board", which seemed natural, but the feature is called something different, "Filter Cards".

More info here: https://help.trello.com/article/787-filtering-cards-on-a-board